# Помогите понять правила роутинга yii2

Tags: php, yii2, роутинг

У меня есть такой url - ***http://site.ru/1***
Есть такое правило

```
'<id:\d+>' => 'main/public-page'
```

и такое

```
'<sid:\d+>/<uid:\d+>' => 'account/account'
```

Они определяют правила для урла, что выше или нет? И если нет, то когда они сработают? При каком урл?

Comment: второе правило однозначно требует двух сегментов url, поэтому они не будут пересекаться

Comment: а первое правило?

Comment: а первое правило сработает только на одном численном сегменте

Comment: то есть, оно сработает для этого -  `http://site.ru/1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последовательность обработки правил, является последовательностью в массиве правил. Да у вас сработает первое правило для http://site.ru/1

```
'<id:\d+>' => 'main/public-page'
```

/1 => MainController/actionPublicPage($id=1)

```
'<sid:\d+>/<uid:\d+>' => 'account/account'
```

/1/2 => AccountController/actionAccount($sid=1, $uid=2)

Как пример для наглядности еще пару правил

```
'<action:[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+>' => 'web/default/<action>',
```

/login => WebModule/DefaultController/actionLogin

/profile => WebModule/DefaultController/actionProfile

```
'<action:[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+>/<token:\d+\-[A-Fa-f0-9]+>' => 'web/default/<action>'
```

/activate?token=FA123 => WebModule/DefaultController/actionActivate($token='FA123')